# Java String Should Contain Only Letters and Dot

Tags: java, string

I would like to write a checker for my string input, I only wants my string to have capital letters and "`.`".

I am thinking about writing code like `a.match("^([A-Za-z]+$");` but I don't know how to exclude "`.`" from this statement. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[A-Z.]+` should do the trick. Note, that you also don't want small letters.

`^` and `$` are not required because `String.matches` operates on the complete String.

The `.` requires no escape, because within character classes (the `[...]` part) a `.` has no special meaning.

Comment: Didn't know that part about no need to escape dot! :)

Comment: I prefer to be explicit with regex's. It doesn't leave room for error if you move them around to different languages or editors.

Comment: @b1naryj: Do mean the `^$` part or the dot part? The dot part is standard in any regexp engine.